# Python RQ and Redis Server: How does the worker know the function code to execute?

Tags: python, redis, queue, jobs, rq

So I would like to have the following architecture:

Flask API (VM 1) -> Redis Server (VM 2) <- Worker (VM 3)

I have seen some examples and the idea I get is that on the API you define the tasks that handle the jobs (workers will perform) and push it to Redis queue.
What I am not understanding is, how does a remote worker knows the code of the function handler to execute? All the examples I have seen have the worker on the same directory as the API code...
Does the Redis Server stores the byte-codes of the function that the worker will execute?
Do I have to spawn a worker and link it to the code which has all the task handlers code?

Please elucidate me...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand from [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs) guide code that you want to execute must be on worker machine when you create a job.
Example from this guide:

```
rq_job = current_app.task_queue.enqueue('app.tasks.' + name, self.id,
                                                *args, **kwargs)
```

in app.tasks+'name' you describe path for .py file that stored in Worker.

So Redis store info about jobs and Workers execute code that describes in jobs.